# Information leakage due to superposition

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-measurements

My question is going to be a bit sketchy so please forgive me.

Imagine the following experiment:
-We have a particle that is in a superposition of space, such that $\psi(x)$ has the form of two gaussians at $p_0$ and $-p_0$(suppose the gaussians are concentrated enough around their center). 
-Now we make the two gaussians move apart(or we can directly imagine they were enough distant so that information can't classically travel between them during the experiment). Alice will be at $p$ and Bob at $-p$.
-Now, based on the information Alice wants to encode(0 or 1), she will try to "force the wave function to collapse where she is"(if it's 1, if it's 0 she won't do anything). 
-After an agreed time they chose(taking into consideration time correction), Bob will "try to force the wave function to collapse where he is". If he finds the particle this means that Alice didn't measure it. If he doesn't it's been measured by Alice.

This way(with some probability due to the ability to successfully collapse the wave on the 2 ends, which is a statistical phenomena), they can transfer information.

Since it's not possible where is the error?

My principal thought is that it has to do with trying to measure the particle just in a place. But it's not obvious to me why that's not possible.
I was thinking that if I for example make my gaussian crash onto a screen, I might have a good chance of "making it interact" and thus measuring it there.
Can you clarify how measurement work here?
For example if Alice makes a measurement she can't make the function collapse on Bob right? To me that doesn't make sense. But at the same time the "measurement" made this way differs from acting $\hat{x}|\psi>$ since it could make my wave collapse in a totally different place.

And finally, regarding the "forcing a measurement", what I mean is "trying to measure it by interacting". If I don't interact in my mind the measurement didn't take place, and I repeat until I measure. (But again feel free to correct me if this is wrong)

Comment: Your question(s) seem very confused, and you ask many things at once, making it hard to follow what exactly you are asking for. I also suggest to put everything into math...

Comment: Regarding math it's not much needed here. Regarding the main question is: Where is the error in the protocol I described? The following questions where to help describe better where my doubt lies.

Comment: Well, I do think math would help here and is indeed needed, else everything is hollow words. And indeed, if you'd do the math (including some implicit assumptions), you would find the error in your line of reasoning. See e.g. the no-communication theorem, which, roughly, shows that within the formalism of QM, any action Alice could possibly do to her particle, cannot change the probability distribution of Bob's possible measurements; in particular, Bob cannot know whether or not Alice has measured something.

Comment: If you think math would help feel free to add it. Btw I didn't knew about no-communication theorem. I looked it up and it doesn't apply here. We only have 1 system here, so they don't live in different hilbert spaces. A problem I have putting it into math is that as mentioned in the question the measure is implemented by the x operator. But this operator if applied can only give Alice values she has access to. So I don't see how she can both make a measure, and get a position value at -p(at Bob's). The way I thought this is that when she tries to interact to make the measure she might fail, so

Comment: -so she won't actually make any measure. So mathematically woud be like acting with identity. But this line of reasoning evem thought it seems logical looks super cursed. What am I thinking wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem with your argument is that when Alice makes an observation that collapses the wavefunction where she is, that *doesn't* mean she will see the particle and Bob won't. Alice might look, and see no particle, which means Bob will.

We can set up something very like your experiment in reality. We place a radioactive atom in the centre of a space between two hemispherical phosphor screens, one belonging to Alice, one belonging to Bob. The atom decays and flings off an electron in some random direction. The wavefunction is a spherical wave, travelling outwards. When it hits the screen observed by Alice or Bob, the wavefunction collapses so that the electron only shows up at one point on the spherical wavefront, and no other. If it hits Alice's screen, it never shows up on Bob's, and vice versa.

But each observer sees either a flash of light or no flash, at random. Or if one of them chooses not to look, and moves their screen out of the way, then the other will see either a flash of light, or no flash, at random. *Seeing no flash* collapses the electron's wavefunction just as much as *seeing* the flash does. Nothing about this observation tells Bob whether Alice was looking. The only thing Bob knows is that *if* Alice *was* looking, she saw the opposite outcome. And he can only *observe* the correlation when Alice and Bob get back together to compare notes.

Comment: Thank you. I was actually thinking this as a counter example, but I still had a doubt about this. As mentioned in the main question my definition of measuring is repeating measure until I collapse the wave. We could implement this for example by putting Bob's detector much far away, and Alice can either spam a huge amount of detectors continuously trying to detect the particle. Or not putting anything. If Alice puts a lot of screens does she have a higher chance of detecting the particle that if she kind of let the particle go making sure it doesn't interact with anything?

Comment: If it's measured, that collapses the wave. Measuring again makes no difference, you just get the same result (evolved in time). So let's say Alice sets up a cloud chamber, so the electron bumps into lots of molecules, triggering droplets to form all along the path. Alice sees a track. Bob sees nothing. Or Alice sees nothing, and Bob sees the electron using whatever instrument he has. It doesn't change the odds at all. It has an equal chance of being seen anywhere on the spherical wavefront. Nothing Alice can do can affect the odds of Bob seeing the particle.

Comment: Yes, the point is that if Alice try to measure it but sees nothing this doesn't mean it's been measured. It means she failed to measure it. So the particle is still in a superposition. So the reason she tries another measure is to make the particle collapse. This assuming Bob is making sure to not make the particle interact with anything on his end.

Comment: No, if Alice is making a there/not there observation, and sees it's not there, that's an observation. The wavefunction collapses. That guarantees Bob is going to see it. That guarantees if Alice makes more observations, none of those will see anything either. A cloud chamber track does not start halfway up the path, when multiple attempts to make it collapse finally succeed. It produces a full track, or nothing at all. If Alice tries to see it and doesn't, and there is no collapse, then it would be possible for Bob not to see it either, which would mean the electron had impossibly vanished.

Comment: Thank you. I think I got what you meant. I'm 95% convinced now. Maybe in the future I'll understand a bit better why not measuring something is a measure lol. Even thought it sounds logical it's weird since the experimenter literally collapsed a wave, but his experiment literally didn't do anything, there could not have been anything from the start and it wouldn't make a difference. But I half get it.

Comment: You're welcome. It might help to think of it as a process of elimination. It's like you're looking for the ball under one of three cups. You lift two of the three cups, and don't see it. So you know the third cup must hide the ball. You have found it (measured its location) without ever actually seeing it! If you think about it like that, it is quite weird.

Answer (score 1):

> Bob will "try to force the wave function to collapse where he is". If he finds the particle this means that Alice didn't measure it. If he doesn't it's been measured by Alice.

Bob doesn't have a tool to ask "has Alice done a measurement of the entangled particle?" or "does this particle still exist in a superposition with Alice's particle?".

Bob can always "find the particle" and can measure that particle.   But the value of that measurement can't distinguish whether Alice has or has not performed a similar measurement.

Comment: My understanding disagree. If Alice measures her particle, the wave collapses, so Bob can try to measure it as much as he want but $|\psi>$ at his position is 0. This actually made me realise that it's even scarier. A third observer could see Bob measuring the particle before Alice did.

Answer (score 1):

Bob measures the state where he is.

Based on Bob's state measurement, Bob knows what Alice *will* measure *if* she measures the state where she is and what she *would have* measured *if* she has already measured the state.

The basic fact of this is not especially spooky. Suppose Alice and Bob pack their lunches and get on their space ships. After flying apart several light seconds, Bob opens his lunch box and finds Alice's lunch. He instantly knows what Alice will find, or has found, when she opens her lunch box several light seconds away.

The thing that makes the particle version a little bit spooky is that, unlike the lunch box contents, we know that the quantum probability distribution isn't just an expression of Bob's and Alice's ignorance, but an expression of something true about the universe outside of Bob and Alice.

Comment: I agree. Thanks for the response but this doesn't answer the question right? The difference with the classical case is that this way it looks that Alice can decide wether she gets the lunch or not(and she can decide this at a relativistic distance)

Comment: @sonoda It does. Bob can't receive a signal from Alice by measuring his particle, because his measurement doesn't tell him anything about whether Alice has actually measured hers, only what she must have measured or must measure in the future if she does measure it.

Comment: But on the same note "if Alice measured it, after this Bob won't measure it. If Alice didn't measure it Bob can either measure it or not". So doesn't Bob can tell if Alice tried to measure it if he doesn't find it?

Comment: (I'm assuming that a measurement made by Alice can only make the function collapse where Alice is, and not where Bob is. If this is the case Alice can decise to collapse the wave, but can't decide where it collapses. In this case I'd agree that measures are correlated, but no information get codified. But I don't think Alice can make it collapse at Bob. Do you agree with this?)